# Enable or disable a task in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a few executable files to execute one by one. e.g.

```
A_1.sh
B_0.sh
cs_2.sh
c_4.sh
3_d.sh
```

I can execute all files with the following script, but I can't able to disable one, if I don't need that.

```
#!/bin/sh
for type in \
A_1 \
B_0 \
cs_2 \
c_4 \
3_d 
do
echo executing $type.sh
done
```

When I am disabling one e.g.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    for type in \
    A_1 \
    B_0 \
#    cs_2 \
    c_4 \
    3_d 
    do
    echo executing $type.sh
    done
```

It is showing syntax error near c_4. How to handle it actually?

Comment: It shows syntax error because ``\`` before c_4 is commented out. You might want to use a workaround like storing the list in an array first. Array elements when declared aren't needed to be quoted with ``\`` when defined using multiple lines.

Comment: Also `bash != sh`

Comment: @Jetchisel Right I missed that. Better remove the tag until OP explicitly says it's bash.

Comment: Why do you need a loop and don't just `./A1.sh; ./B0.sh; ./cs2.sh;`? Seems redundant to first define a loop with all items to then call the items. If you really need it: print the names and `read -r` them or use `xargs`?

Comment: In addition to the valid comments given here, I wonder why you want to enable/disable it by **commenting out** something. Changing an editor every time  I want to enable/disable something in a script is error prone, and I would prefer not doing it. Instead, control it from the outside (via parameter, or environment variables, or a configuration file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to use Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(
  A_1
  B_0
  # This is a comment
  # cs_2
  c_4
  3_d
) 
for type in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo executing $type.sh
done
```

You can read from a here document and filter comments:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r -u 3 line; do
   # Is a comment?
   if grep '^ *#' <<<"$line"; then continue; fi
   # Close fd3, on the safe side.
   echo executing $type.sh <&3-
done 3<<EOF
A_1
B_0
# This is a comment
# cs_2
c_4
3_d
EOF
```

Or invert the logic, do a function:

```
run() {
  echo executing $1.sh
}
run A_1
run B_0
# run cs_2
run c_4
run 3_d
```